# Combining 2 views into one, and placing one below the other

Tags: java, android, layout

I add 2 layout types (on top of the default one), one of which adds some names to the top of some rows and another layout to add buttons to the screen (and a black line). 
However I want the bar at the top with the names to remain constant, and to add the buttons in a loop, that I can scroll through. So far the code for this I have written is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ScrollView scrollPictures = new ScrollView(this);
    RelativeLayout mainApp = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LinearLayout appLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    appLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    appLayout.setClipBounds(null);

    for(int x = 1; x <= 15; x++){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button_layout, appLayout, false);


        Button StudentSubmission = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        StudentSubmission.setText("Button 1");
        StudentSubmission.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        Button SoundButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        SoundButton.setText("Button 2");
        SoundButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        appLayout.addView(view);

    }

    scrollPictures.addView(appLayout);
    View topmenuview = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.topofmenu, mainApp, false);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams q = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    q.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, scrollPictures.getId());

    mainApp.addView(scrollPictures, p);
    mainApp.addView(topmenuview, q);
    setContentView(mainApp);
}
```

However, with this code the bar with the names of columns is placed ON TOP of the list of buttons rather than being ABOVE them, resulting in the top button being cut off. Is there a way to get the buttons to appear UNDER the names of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
q.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, scrollPictures.getId());

mainApp.addView(scrollPictures, p);
mainApp.addView(topmenuview, q);
```

should be

```
q.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, topmenuview.getId());

mainApp.addView(topmenuview, p);
mainApp.addView(scrollPictures, q);
```

right?